# identify line in a jtextpane when the row number is entered

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

```
           public static void setJTextPaneFont(JTextPane jtp, Color c, int start_index,int end_index) {

    MutableAttributeSet attrs = jtp.getInputAttributes();
    StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, c);
    StyledDocument doc = jtp.getStyledDocument();
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(start_index, end_index, attrs, false);
}
```

i created above code to change the forground of of specific word when i enter the start ndex and end index.But now i need to change the the forground when i pass the row number,start_index, and end index.Can you help me with this.How i identify a specific line when i enter the row number.

```
     public void gotoStartOfLine(JTextComponent component, int line) {
           Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
           line = Math.max(line, 1);
           line = Math.min(line, root.getElementCount());
           component.setCaretPosition(root.getElement(line - 1).getStartOffset());
     }
```

i tried above code to go to specific row.but it didint work

Comment: Is the start/end index based on the current line??

Comment: yes.start index and end index based on the row that is selected

Comment: `i tried above code to go to specific row.but it didint work` - The method as coded does not do what you want. I suggested that you need to `"borrow"` the code to get the start offset of the given line number. I actually just updated the class to make this concept clearer. So you may want to download the new version. You will need your own version of that method to return the `startOfLineOffset` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How i identify a specific line when i enter the row number.

I think you mean you want the offset of the text for the given row. If so then take a look at the  `gotoStartOfLine()` method from [Text Utilities](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/).

That is the code that sets the caret position will give you the starting offset of the line. Then you just add the start/end values to get the offsets of the text to highlight.

Comment: @user2771059, You didn't change the code, you just copied the code which won't solve your problem. Read my additional comment from above.

Answer (score 1):

Look at using the [javax.swing.text.Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html) class, especially the `getRowStart(...)` and `getRowEnd(...)` methods.

Comment: i want to get the specific word and change the color when i enter the row number start index and end index

Comment: @user2771059: OK, my choice of methods may be off, but check the API for that class, because it will have the method(s) that you need.