# How to find out line numbers of selected text?

Tags: java, button, listener

Assume this very small program:

```
 1.  package ex1;    
 2.  public interface Resizable {
 3.  void resize();
 4.  }
```

In my editor, if I select line 2-3 using mouse and say click on a button, I want to highlight these texts and also print, which line numbers were selected exactly for the button.

I can do the highlighting part, but I don't know how to find the line numbers of highlighted texts, As I think, I should use a listener, which will detect any changes in editor.

I think I should use an action listener, which will detect when the button is pressed after selecting text blocks. But how I will know, which lines are selected exactly?

Comment: is this correctly labelled as `java` and `jquery` at the same time? What is the framework that you are using?

Comment: Sorry, its related to Java. Jquery popped up as tag suggestion and I thought it has relevance with this question. I removed the tag.

Comment: So are you using Swing? (for buttons, windows, etc?) (check the package name of the Button class, for example)

Comment: Yes, I am using swing. I have done the highlighting part, but can't retrieve the line information's from it.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754940/identify-line-in-a-jtextpane-when-the-row-number-is-entered and this

Comment: And look at class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start and end of the highlight can be taken from the caret position `dot` and `mark` respectively. These are offsets in the `Document`. You must then calculate the number of newlines from the start of the document until the mark/do

```
    textArea.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
            int startLine = getLine(e.getDot());
            int endLine = getLine(e.getMark());
            ...
        }
    });

private int getLine(int offset) {
    String text = textArea.getDocument().getText(0, offset);
    int linenr = 0;
    int idx = text.indexOf("\n");
    while (idx != -1) {
        linenr++;
        idx = text.indexOf("\n", idx);
    }
    return linenr;
}
```